# Passing pointer to SOCKADDR_IN and SOCKET in a function

Tags: c, windows, function, winapi, pointers

I have a function *createServerSocket()*. This function can be accessed by multiple threads for creating their sockets.

I want each thread to pass three arguments, a *socketIdentifier*, *sockaddr_in* and specific *port number* to *createrServerSocket()* function, so that each thread has a unique socket.

For this, I am passing *socketIdentifier*, *sockaddr_in* and specific *port number* to createrServerSocket() function as pointers so that socketIdentifier and socket created must be accessable inside thread.

Below is my code snippet:

```
VOID createServerSocket(SOCKADDR_IN *socket, SOCKET *socketIdentifier, int PORT)
{

   //Socket Binding//
   WSADATA wsa; 

   //Initialise winsock//
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
      {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

   //Create a socket//
   if((*socketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
      {                 
         MessageBox(NULL,
                    "Socket not Created",
                    "Failure :(",
                    MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   //Socket Created//

   //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure//
   *socket.sin_family = AF_INET;
   *socket.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   *socket.sin_port = htons( PORT );

   //Bind//
   if( bind(socketIdentifier ,(struct sockaddr *)&socket , sizeof(socket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {             
         MessageBox(NULL,
                    "Bind Failed",
                    "Failure :(",
                    MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   //Else Bind Done//
   MessageBox(NULL,
              "Bind Done",
              "SUCCESS :)",
              MB_ICONINFORMATION);

}
```

Here is the calling function:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadProc(LPVOID param)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN socket;
    SOCKET socketIdentifier;
    createServerSocket(*socket,*socketIdentifier,8888); //Create a socket with a socketIdentifier and bind()ed to PORT#8888.
        //Do something at this socket
        Return TRUE;
}
```

These are the errors that I get:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
>   error C2228: left of '.sin_family' must have class/struct/union 
>   error C2228: left of '.sin_addr' must have class/struct/union
>   error C2228: left of '.S_un' must have class/struct/union
>   error C2228: left of '.S_addr' must have class/struct/union 
>   error C2228: left of '.sin_port' must have class/struct/union
>   error C2070: ''unknown-type'': illegal sizeof operand

**Line:**
    if((*socketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)

**Error:**
*error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bind` call is totally wrong, it should be something like:

```
bind(*socketIdentifier, (SOCKADDR*) socket, sizeof(*socket))
```

You also have a problem with precedence in the initialization of the `socket` structure pointer, which leads to your compiler errors. Either use `(*socket).sin_family` etc., or `socket->sin_family` etc. The last one is the common usage of structure pointers.

Comment: Thank you so much. All rest of the problems are solved except 

Line: if((*socketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)

Error: error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments

Comment: @AyeshaHassan It's because you already have a local variable (the argument) named `socket`. Rename that variable and you can call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable named socket that is causing issues and compiler errors in your function createServerSocket.  Please try something like this:

```
VOID createServerSocket(SOCKADDR_IN& sock, SOCKET& socketIdentifier, int PORT)
{

   //Socket Binding//
   WSADATA wsa; 

   //Initialise winsock//
   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
      {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

   //Create a socket//
   if((socketIdentifier = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
      {                 
         MessageBox(NULL,
                    "Socket not Created",
                    "Failure :(",
                    MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   //Socket Created//

   //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure//
   sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
   sock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   sock.sin_port = htons( PORT );

}

DWORD WINAPI threadProc(LPVOID param)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sock;
    SOCKET socketIdentifier;
    createServerSocket(sock,socketIdentifier,8888); //Create a socket with a socketIdentifier and bind()ed to PORT#8888.
        //Do something at this socket
        return TRUE;
}
```